# Evolution of an average over time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, calculation

I have a Snowflake table that tracks rating level per ID over time. I want to find the running or cumulative average per day to track the company's progress over time. One ID can have multiple iterations as the rating level gets updated over time.

I would like to know how to calculate the running average while accounting for the iterations. For example, ID Number T390-23 has two iterations. I want to include the first iteration rating value in the running average until it is updated and then I want to disregard it from that time onward and use the second iteration until a third comes along.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DLDS.png)
[Sample data with the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrWiz.png)

I was able to successfully calculate the running average, but it gives undesired results when including IDs with two or more iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of a scalar lookup to calculate the average after associating each rating with an expiration date. I don't have access to Snowflake so there may be some small syntax or date format issues with the query as written:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        lead(assessment_date, 1, '2099-12-31') over (partition by id_number order by iteration) as valid_until
    from T
)
select *,
    (select avg(d.rating_level) from data d
     where d.assessment_date < t.assessment_date and t.assessment_date < d.valid_until) as running_average
from T t;
```